# How do I make a WiX 3.5 installer with a completely self-contained .NET 4.0 installer?

Tags: wix, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2010

Continuing a previous question [I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128734/how-do-i-make-a-wix-installer-with-a-completely-self-contained-net-3-5-sp1-insta), I now need to move to vs2010.

I've gotten the most recent weekly build of WiX 3.5, the June 5th 2010 version.

Here's the relevant lines from my installer:

```
      <ItemGroup>
        <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.4.0">
          <ProductName>.NET Framework 4.0</ProductName>
        </BootstrapperFile>
        <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.4.5">
         <ProductName>Windows Installer 4.5</ProductName>
       </BootstrapperFile>
      </ItemGroup>
```

and

```
<GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="MySetup.msi" ApplicationName="MyProgram" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\" ComponentsLocation="Relative" OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" Culture="en" />
```

However, it's just not working.  In vs2010, there are exclamation points next to the .NET Framework 4.0 and Windows Installer 4.5 files, and the properties page lists them as 'Unknown BuildAction BootstrapperFile', and the build just does not appear to install .NET 4.0 at all.  The relevant warning is:

```
C:\source\depot\project\vs2010\WiXSetup\WiXSetup.wixproj(68,5): warning MSB3155: Item 'Microsoft.Net.Framework.4.0' could not be located in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\'.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is to change

```
<ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1" >
       <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperFile>
    <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1" >
       <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperFile>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="setup">
    <GenerateBootstrapper
        ApplicationFile="myproduct.msi"
        ApplicationName="myproduct"
        BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)"
        Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\"
        ComponentsLocation="Relative"
        OutputPath="$(cddir)"
        Culture="en"/>
</Target>
```

to

```
<ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperFile Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" >
       <ProductName>.NET Framework 4.0</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperFile>
    <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1" >
       <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperFile>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="setup">
    <GenerateBootstrapper
        ApplicationFile="myproduct.msi"
        ApplicationName="myproduct"
        BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)"
        Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\"
        ComponentsLocation="Relative"
        OutputPath="$(cddir)"
        Culture="en"/>
</Target>
```

I figured this out by going into the SDK bootstrapper directory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper) on my machine, for Visual Studios 2010.  Under there is a list of projects that can be read by Wix and included for bootstrapping.  In each folder there is a file called Product.xml.  After looking at the help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128734/how-do-i-make-a-wix-installer-with-a-completely-self-contained-net-3-5-sp1-insta) for creating a .NET 3.5 installer  I found that the ProductCode attribute in the Product tag appears to identify the name of the boostrap element, so when I changed the value to that referenced in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40\Product.xml it worked.

Comment: This got it, thanks.  I'm glad they decided to change the structure of their commands, that was very helpful and necessary. </sarcasm>

Comment: I was also having this problem in VS2010, and this solution worked perfectly (thank you!), except for the cosmetic issue that the exclamation point still persists next to the bootstrapped packages. Nevertheless, the installer builds completely with bootstrapped packages, and installs as expected. If anyone knows what causes the exclamation point, and how to get rid of it, please add that here. Thanks!