# WIX Installer: .NET 3.5 and .net 4.x

Tags: c#, .net, wix

Using WIX Toolset 3.11, custom bootstrapper.

Product has minimum requirements of Windows 7 SP1, all the way up to Windows 10.  Another wrinkle is that the machine the user may be installing on may not be connected to the internet to download anything.

The end goal is to have .NET 4.6.2 installed prior to executing the installed product.  I have a package in my installer that installs .NET 4.6.2 silently.  I didn't use the NetFxExtension, because I couldn't figure out how to include the .NET installer for offline installation (all the redist stuff I tried didn't work).

Here comes the problem:

Windows 7 SP1, the default .NET installation is 3.5.
Windows 10, it's 4.something, 3.5 shows as installed in the registry, but not necessarily in the Add or Remove Programs screen.

When I execute the installer on Windows 10, I get my installer UI.
When I execute the installer on Windows 7, I get "Microsoft .NET Framework required for <application> setup".  This SEEMS like it's a problem with the BootstrapperCore.config, which is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="wix.bootstrapper" type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperSectionGroup, BootstrapperCore">
      <section name="host" type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.HostSection, BootstrapperCore" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    <!-- I've tried adding <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> here too.  Didn't work. -->
  </startup>
  <wix.bootstrapper>
    <host assemblyName="ApplicationBootstrapper">
      <supportedFramework version="v2.0.50727" />
      <supportedFramework version="v4.0" />
    </host>
  </wix.bootstrapper>
</configuration>
```

It does get through the detect phase, which starts prior to the UI being displayed (I start the detect, then start the UI).

I've checked all the "Similar Questions" suggested by Stack Overflow, as well as digging around the various WIX bootstrapper websites.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017805/how-do-i-make-a-wix-3-5-installer-with-a-completely-self-contained-net-4-0-inst) is the closest thing I've found, but it's for msbuild bootstrappers, not burn bootstrappers.

Comment: How you are detecting .net in your Bundle (*.wxs) code?

Comment: I rolled my own, using the method used by the Wix NetFx extension.  Since then, I've switched to using the WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_462_OR_LATER_INSTALLED variable, but I haven't tested it yet, as there are several problems with this installer and this got bumped to lower priority.

Comment: I copied code from Wix Source and using directly inside my Bundle code. Here is the link to NetFx 4.6.2 detect and install.
https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx462.wxs