# Wix Bootstrapper should take installfiles from subfolders

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a WiX installer with a completely self-contained .NET 3.5 sp1 installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128734/how-do-i-make-a-wix-installer-with-a-completely-self-contained-net-3-5-sp1-inst)

Is there any possibility to say the WIX-Bootstrapper to take the Installfiles located in the subdirectories? When starting the strapper he always wants to download the newest versions (.net, Installer, etc).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128734/how-do-i-make-a-wix-installer-with-a-completely-self-contained-net-3-5-sp1-insta)